# Add to array index according to each letter of user input

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

So I am trying to create a short as possible function that will:

1. Get the user input as a string and put it into an array of const char.
2. Use a for loop to and get the alphabetical position of the current index in the for loop, for the entire const char array.
3. Then use the alphabetical order as an index, and add one to that index in an array of 26 integers.

So in short: it records the frequency of characters in a string and adds it to an array of integers, so if I input "ABC" it will output 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, etc, or if I input "XXYZZ" it will output ...0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2.

I have taken a shot at this, but it doesn't seem to work;

```
void addCommonToArray(int alphabet_common[], string userinput) {

const char * alphabet = userinput.c_str(); // String to array
int index;

for (int i = 1; i == sizeof(alphabet); i++) {
    index = alphabet[i] - 64; // Get current index and minus 64 from ascii code to get alphabetical order
    alphabet_common[index]++; // Add one to the position of the current index in the alphabet
} }
```

I have revised through this multiple times but fail to seem an issue, yet the `alphabet_common` array is blank. (Also in `main.cpp` there is an array of 26 integers, but all elements of the array are 0) So the problem here is the array stays at 0.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: what will sizeof(alphabet) give you? shouldn't you be looping through userinput.length() and why is i == sizeof(alphabet)?

Comment: @Nik It is so the for loop knows where to stop, in this case, once i is equal to the size of the array. sizeof(alphabet) gives me how many elements there are in the array.

Comment: will you ever enter the for loop? what will sizeof(alphabet) give you?

Comment: And thats why you have -3 on your question :)

Comment: And you yourself confessed in your answer "Apparently the for loop wasn't even executing, but the above seems to work."

Comment: Why are you so aggressive, sorry for asking a question and finding an answer (no thanks to anyone on this website) lmao

Comment: Sorry if I sounded aggressive. But you are missing the point. If I had wanted to answer the question I could have done it. But I gave you some questions/hints: 1. will you ever enter the for loop, 2. sizeof(alphabet), this will always return size of pointer and not string array, 3. I gave you hint to use userinput.length(), do you still think I did not help you?

Comment: And do you know people answering and commenting and reading your question on this site spend their time to help others. Many people have contributed immensely to make STACKOVERFLOW a HUGE platform, so choose your words carefully. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it,

```
void addCommonToArray(int alphabet_common[], string userinput) {
int index;
for (char& c : userinput) {
    index = toupper(c) - 64;
    alphabet_common[index]++;
} }
```

Apparently the for loop wasn't even executing, but the above seems to work.

Comment: what is your purpose here? how can you be asking such question here?

Comment: Elaborate? Are beginners not welcome here? Oh, shame.